# 2d array error - makes pointer to integer without cast

Tags: c, arrays

hello to stackoverflow community. this will be my first post here seeking help after I scanned many pages of this site and more sites trying to figure out whats wrong with my code. a little background - this is an assignment given to me in an introduction to c course. I have no advanced knowledge of it and any other programming language so go easy on me. I need to write a program that uses two functions I wrote to find the sum distance between a cell in a 2d array and its neighbor to the right. also I need to count the number of elements that are bigger than all their neighbors. here is my shot at this:

```
1)#include <stdio.h>
2)#define N 4
3)int is_strong(int matrix[][N], int row, int column);
4)int Space_rank(int matrix[][N], int row, int column);
5)int My_abs(int);
6)int main()
7){
8)  int matrix[N][N];
9)  printf("Please enter a matrix: \n");
10) for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
11) {
12)   for(int j=0; j<N; j++) scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
13) }
14) int Strong_Amount=0, Total_Space=0;
15) for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
16) {
17)    for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
18)   {
19)        Strong_Amount+=is_strong(matrix[N][N], i, j);
20)        Total_Space+=Space_rank(matrix[N][N], i, j);
21)    }}
22)    printf("Strong elements: %d\n Space rank: %d\n", Strong_Amount,Total_Space);
23)    return 0;
24)}
25)
26)int is_strong (int mat[N][N], int row, int column)
27){
28) int Below, Above, Right, Left;
29) int Subject=mat[row][column];
30) Below=mat[row+1][column];
31) Above=(row-1!=0)*mat[row-1][column];
32) Right=mat[row][column+1];
33) Left=(column-1!=0)*mat[row][column-1];
34) int Answer=(Subject>Above && Subject>Below && Subject>Right && Subject>Left);
35) return Answer;
36)}
37)
38)int Space_rank(int mat[N][N], int row, int column)
39){
40) int Subject=mat[row][column], Right;
41) Right=mat[row][column+1];
42) int Space=My_abs(Subject-Right);
43) return Space;
44)}
45)
46)int My_abs(int v)
47){
48) return v*((v>0)-(v<0));
49)}
```

I am getting an error saying "error: passing argument 1 of 'is_strong' makes pointer from integer without a cast" line 19 . I think that my problem is with the two functions conflicting types but I cant see to find what I did wrong.
any help/tips will be appreciated

Comment: is_strong expects a 2d array, you're giving it an int.

Comment: Indeed.. read up about the difference between _declaring_ an array (parameter or regular variable) and _accessing_ an array.

Comment: thank you both. I am now reading about the differences between declaring and accessing an array

Comment: Posting code with line numbers prevents others from readily compiling your code.  Best to not post with line numbers.  Add a comment in comment to indicate "line 19"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you pass your array to the functions:

```
19)        Strong_Amount+=is_strong(matrix, i, j);
20)        Total_Space+=Space_rank(matrix, i, j);
```

Comment: thank you very much for the quick answer. the code works!

Comment: In That case you could give a thumbs up and mark the answer as correct ;)